# Calculate size of the image after zooming in android

Tags: android, zooming

In my project I have to zoom an image and then save the zoomed image.I can zoom the image but I can’t get the value that how much its size increased.
I am zooming the image using following code.

```
float newDist = spacing(event);
Log.d("Venue Page", "newDist=" + newDist);
if (newDist > 10f) {
matrix.set(savedMatrix);
float scale =newDist / oldDist;
matrix.postScale(scale,scale,mid.x,mid.y);
}
view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

How to calculate size of the image after zooming ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
newWidth = oldWidth * scale;

newHeight = oldHeight * scale;
```

Comment: Hi surendra please provide the logic.I am getting same issue.